# Numerical precision for difference of squares

Tags: c++, c, numerical-analysis

in my code I often compute things like the following piece (here C code for simplicity):

```
float cos_theta = /* some simple operations; no cosf call! */;
float sin_theta = sqrtf(1.0f - cos_theta * cos_theta); // Option 1
```

For this example ignore that the argument of the square root might be negative due to imprecisions. I fixed that with additional `fdimf` call. However, I wondered if the following is more precise:

```
float sin_theta = sqrtf((1.0f + cos_theta) * (1.0f - cos_theta)); // Option 2
```

`cos_theta` is between `-1` and `+1` so for each choice there will be situations where I subtract similar numbers and thus will loose precision, right? **What is the most precise and why?**

Comment: `double` usually has more precision than `float`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: And `long double` has even more precision, but `float` is faster for me!

Comment: The most precise computation of `1.0f - cos_theta * cos_theta` is probably `fmaf(cos_theta, -cos_theta, 1.0f)`. But if you are so concerned about speed that you do not want to use `double` for intermediate computations, you shouldn't use `fmaf` on a processor that does not provide it as a single hardware instruction, because it is awfully costly to emulate (my best try at implementing `fmaf` for a processor that does not have it is at http://ideone.com/kx7MXE , it could be tightened a bit but it 1- uses doubles 2- would continue to do a lot of operations after tightening)

Comment: "subtract similar numbers [and thus] will loose precision" is wrong

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yes, `fmaf` is probably too expensive, but thanks nevertheless. My question aims more at what precision I can get "for free".

Comment: @cschwan - Then you're not running on x86 hardware; `float` and `double` calculations are both done with 80 bits on x86. Most of the time, people use `float` for space optimization, not speed.

Comment: @DieterLücking - what's wrong with it? Broadly speaking, subtracting two numbers with similar values gives very low precision because you end up with mostly noise bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most precise way with floats is likely to compute both sin and cos using a single x87 instruction, **[fsincos](http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc116.htm)**.

<strike>However, if you need to do the computation manually, it's best to group arguments with similar magnitudes.  This means the second option is more precise, especially when `cos_theta` is close to 0, where precision matters the most.</strike>

As the article
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) notes:

> The expression x<sup>2</sup> - y<sup>2</sup> is another formula that exhibits catastrophic
>   cancellation. It is **more accurate** to evaluate it as (x - y)(x + y).

Edit: it's more complicated than this.  Although the above is generally true, (x - y)(x + y) is **slightly less accurate** when x and y are of very different magnitudes, as the footnote to the statement explains:

> In this case, (x - y)(x + y) has three rounding errors, but x<sup>2</sup> - y<sup>2</sup> has only two since the rounding error committed when computing the smaller of x<sup>2</sup> and y<sup>2</sup> does not affect the final subtraction.

In other words, taking x - y, x + y, and the product (x - y)(x + y) each introduce rounding errors (3 steps of rounding error).  x<sup>2</sup>, y<sup>2</sup>, and the subtraction x<sup>2</sup> - y<sup>2</sup> also each introduce rounding errors, but the rounding error obtained by squaring a relatively small number (the smaller of x and y) is so negligible that there are effectively only two steps of rounding error, making the difference of squares more precise.

So option 1 is actually going to be more precise.  This is confirmed by dev.brutus's Java test.

Comment: Thats probably true, but I dont call `cosf`; the cosine here is obtained using geometrical relations.

Comment: `fsincos` has flawed argument reduction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hm, could explain the footnote 7 in the article? "[..] it is slightly less accurate than x² - y² if x << y or x >> y". Does this hold true here?

Comment: The Intel FPU trigonometric instructions use a 66-bit value for π. Inputs whose magnitudes exceed π/2 are reduced by subtracting a multiple of this value. (I expect the bound is π/2 but would have to locate specific documentation to be sure.) So there is error even before the actual trigonometric function is calculated. 66 bits may seem precise, but some values representable in floating-point happen to lie close to multiples of π. So their reductions are very near zero. The small error in 66 bits may be large relative to a near-zero value. The larger the input becomes, the worse this is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is it fair to say that if the argument is guaranteed to be small, as it would be for any geometric computation (certainly between -2π and 2π, and perhaps even in the 1st quadrant), then fsincos is still the most accurate?

Comment: The instructions may be the most accurate for the 80-bit floating-point format, but I do not know about 64-bit. (They are not perfect; Intel documentation specifies error is within 1 ULP on recent processors.) For 64-bit, [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/index.html) provides the best possible results for sine and cosine; there are no representable values any closer than the values returned by CRlibm, and they provide a formal proof of that. So, if there is even one `fsincos` result that rounds the wrong way when rounding to 64-bit, then CRlibm is strictly better.

Comment: The last point is interesting. Consider a sine or cosine that ought to be very near the halfway point between two 64-bit floating-point values. Let *u* be the mathematically exact value. Let *v* be *u* correctly rounded to a 64-bit value. CRlibm is proven to return *v*. Suppose `fsincos` returns *w*, and *w* is very close to *u*, but it is just barely on the other side of the halfway point between *v* and its neighbor. Then, when rounded to 64-bit, *w* produces the neighbor, not *v*. So even though the result of `fsincos` is more accurate than CRlibm, rounding it to 64-bit is less accurate.

Comment: (The above is a theoretical possibility. It is realistic; there are just eleven more bits in the significand of an 80-bit float than of a 64-bit float, so about one in 2048 cases may lie near a halfway point, and then you need a little error in `fsincos` to push it over. But I cannot identify one offhand. The CRlibm documentation might have some clues.)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote small test. It calcutates expected value with double precision. Then it calculates an error with your options. The first option is better:

```
Algorithm: FloatTest$1
option 1 error = 3.802792362162126
option 2 error = 4.333273185303996
Algorithm: FloatTest$2
option 1 error = 3.802792362167937
option 2 error = 4.333273185305868
```

The Java code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class FloatTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        testImpl(new ExpectedAlgorithm() {
            public double te(double cos_theta) {
                return Math.sqrt(1.0f - cos_theta * cos_theta);
            }
        });
        testImpl(new ExpectedAlgorithm() {
            public double te(double cos_theta) {
                return Math.sqrt((1.0f + cos_theta) * (1.0f - cos_theta));
            }
        });
    }

    public void testImpl(ExpectedAlgorithm ea) {
        double delta1 = 0;
        double delta2 = 0;
        for (double cos_theta = -1; cos_theta <= 1; cos_theta += 1e-8) {
            double[] delta = delta(cos_theta, ea);
            delta1 += delta[0];
            delta2 += delta[1];
        }

        System.out.println("Algorithm: " + ea.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("option 1 error = " + delta1);
        System.out.println("option 2 error = " + delta2);
    }

    private double[] delta(double cos_theta, ExpectedAlgorithm ea) {
        double expected = ea.te(cos_theta);
        double delta1 = Math.abs(expected - t1((float) cos_theta));
        double delta2 = Math.abs(expected - t2((float) cos_theta));

        return new double[]{delta1, delta2};
    }

    private double t1(float cos_theta) {
        return Math.sqrt(1.0f - cos_theta * cos_theta);
    }

    private double t2(float cos_theta) {
        return Math.sqrt((1.0f + cos_theta) * (1.0f - cos_theta));
    }

    interface ExpectedAlgorithm {
        double te(double cos_theta);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice! But I don't understand the difference between `FloatTest$1` and `FloatTest$2`. Why do you have 4 different numbers (instead of two)? It's been a while since I wrote Java myself.

Comment: I use same options to calculate expected value :) So FloatTest$1 tests with option 1 algorithm. And FloatTest$2 tests with option 2 algorithm.

Comment: Ah, the *expected* value has to be computed as well, right - hello combinatorics ;) !

Comment: It would be nice to have a plot of the error in dependence of `cos_theta`.

Comment: Is this adding the total absolute error sampled over the domain? Why is absolute error an appropriate metric rather than relative error or some other metric?

Comment: Eric, I think it isn't great difference between absolute or relative metric this case. The estimated value is same both options. So this metrics is proportional.
Absolute metric is simle for code.

Comment: I do think there is a difference. Relative error will give more weight to when the result is small (cos_theta close to +1 or -1), which is when I expect trouble for method 1.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to reason about numerical precision of some expression is to:

1. Measure the result discrepancy relative to the correct value in [ULPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (Unit in the last place), introduced in 1960. by W. H. Kahan. You can find C, Python & Mathematica implementations [here](https://github.com/ahrvoje/numerics/tree/master/ulp), and learn more on the topic [here](http://ahrvoje.tumblr.com/post/135115439423/computing-ulp).
2. Discriminate between two or more expressions based on the worst case they produce, not average absolute error as done in other answers or by some other arbitrary metric. This is how numerical approximation polynomials are constructed ([Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm)), how standard library methods' implementations are analysed (e.g. Intel [atan2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-atan2)), etc...

With that in mind, version_1: sqrt(1 - x * x) and version_2: sqrt((1 - x) * (1 + x)) produce significantly different outcomes. As presented in the plot below, version_1 demonstrates catastrophic performance for x close to 1 with error > 1_000_000 ulps, while on the other hand error of version_2 is well behaved.

That is why I always recommend using version_2, i.e. exploiting the square difference formula.

[image]

Python 3.6 code that produces square_diff_error.csv file:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import exp, fabs, sqrt
from random import random
from struct import pack, unpack


def ulp(x):
    """
    Computing ULP of input double precision number x exploiting
    lexicographic ordering property of positive IEEE-754 numbers.

    The implementation correctly handles the special cases:
      - ulp(NaN) = NaN
      - ulp(-Inf) = Inf
      - ulp(Inf) = Inf

    Author: Hrvoje Abraham
    Date: 11.12.2015
    Revisions: 15.08.2017
               26.11.2017
    MIT License https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

    :param x: (float) float ULP will be calculated for
    :returns: (float) the input float number ULP value
    """

    # setting sign bit to 0, e.g. -0.0 becomes 0.0
    t = abs(x)

    # converting IEEE-754 64-bit format bit content to unsigned integer
    ll = unpack('Q', pack('d', t))[0]

    # computing first smaller integer, bigger in a case of ll=0 (t=0.0)
    near_ll = abs(ll - 1)

    # converting back to float, its value will be float nearest to t
    near_t = unpack('d', pack('Q', near_ll))[0]

    # abs takes care of case t=0.0
    return abs(t - near_t)


with open('e:/square_diff_error.csv', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(100_000):
        # nonlinear distribution of x in [0, 1] to produce more cases close to 1
        k = 10
        x = (exp(k) - exp(k * random())) / (exp(k) - 1)

        fx = Fraction(x)
        correct = sqrt(float(Fraction(1) - fx * fx))

        version1 = sqrt(1.0 - x * x)
        version2 = sqrt((1.0 - x) * (1.0 + x))

        err1 = fabs(version1 - correct) / ulp(correct)
        err2 = fabs(version2 - correct) / ulp(correct)

        f.write(f'{x},{err1},{err2}\n')
```

Mathematica code that produces the final plot:

```
data = Import["e:/square_diff_error.csv"];

err1 = {1 - #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ data;
err2 = {1 - #[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ data;

ListLogLogPlot[{err1, err2}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {"1-x", "error [ULPs]"}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}]
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you say that Method 1 ist best when `x` is small. What happens if `x` is close to `1`? What I am unsure about is whether I agree with your method of measuring the error. I think you are assuming that the precision is linearly distributed, since you divide by `ulp(correct)`. Wouldn't it be better to measure the number of next-representable floating-point numbers between the correct and approximated results?

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above, in C I would use the smallest number of (`correct` and `approximated`) and check how often I have to call `nextafter` till I get a number that is larger than the largest of (`exact`, `approximated`). What would be wrong with that approach?

Comment: Method 1 is good when x is small. For x near 1, lot of precision gets 'rounded off' during computing x\*x, so you loose important bits and you are not able to get precise 1-x*x. In method 2 the expression is divided into small & large parts which are computed exactly, and larger part 1+x just plays a role of correction for small part 1-x. As 1+x<2 you will never get big precision problem, cumulative error should always be near 1ulp or so. This part is not easy to explain in short textual form, but can be checked by numerical experimentation, and in the most strict approach by math. theorem.

Comment: You are correct that using number of float representables between correct & incorrect value is one way of measure. Nevertheless, I always tend to implement Kahan's approach which is a consistent use a single error measure which gives the largest possible error output, and this is generally to divide with ulp(correct). These two approaches are injective, so during the comparison you'll always end up with the same worst case conclusion.

Comment: Additionally, in a case of analysis of very precise methods for which the error doesn't even exceed 1ulp, it is of little worth to count the number of representables, as there are none in between, and by dividing with ulp(correct) you can get fractional error like 0.2ulp, 0.7ulp... For some functions it is essential to contain the error within [0, 0.5] ulp.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that - I didn't think of the case that one could be interested in fractional errors. But I still don't understand why you divide by ulp(correct). Wouldn't you divide by `min(ulp(correct), ulp(approximated))` to get the maximum error?

Comment: This is a matter of computing the error generally, not only for floating point needs, you always compare it to some characteristic of the correct result, not an incorrect one. There is no theorem that proves dividing with ulp(correct) is the best way to do it, but this approach survived all use & edge cases last 50+ yrs, and there are many of them...

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you will always have a problem when theta is small, because the cosine is flat around theta = 0. If theta is between -0.0001 and 0.0001 then cos(theta) in float is exactly one, so your sin_theta will be exactly zero.

To answer your question, when cos_theta is close to one (corresponding to a small theta), your second computation is clearly more accurate. This is shown by the following program, that lists the absolute and relative errors for both computations for various values of cos_theta. The errors are computed by comparing against a value which is computed with 200 bits of precision, using GNU MP library, and then converted to a float.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main() 
{
  int i;
  printf("cos_theta       abs (1)    rel (1)       abs (2)    rel (2)\n\n");
  for (i = -14; i < 0; ++i) {
    float x = 1 - pow(10, i/2.0);
    float approx1 = sqrt(1 - x * x);
    float approx2 = sqrt((1 - x) * (1 + x));

    /* Use GNU MultiPrecision Library to get 'exact' answer */
    mpf_t tmp1, tmp2;
    mpf_init2(tmp1, 200);  /* use 200 bits precision */
    mpf_init2(tmp2, 200);
    mpf_set_d(tmp1, x);
    mpf_mul(tmp2, tmp1, tmp1);  /* tmp2 = x * x */
    mpf_neg(tmp1, tmp2);        /* tmp1 = -x * x */
    mpf_add_ui(tmp2, tmp1, 1);  /* tmp2 = 1 - x * x */
    mpf_sqrt(tmp1, tmp2);       /* tmp1 = sqrt(1 - x * x) */
    float exact = mpf_get_d(tmp1);

    printf("%.8f     %.3e  %.3e     %.3e  %.3e\n", x,
           fabs(approx1 - exact), fabs((approx1 - exact) / exact),
           fabs(approx2 - exact), fabs((approx2 - exact) / exact));
    /* printf("%.10f  %.8f  %.8f  %.8f\n", x, exact, approx1, approx2); */
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
cos_theta       abs (1)    rel (1)       abs (2)    rel (2)

0.99999988     2.910e-11  5.960e-08     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99999970     5.821e-11  7.539e-08     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99999899     3.492e-10  2.453e-07     1.164e-10  8.178e-08
0.99999684     2.095e-09  8.337e-07     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99998999     1.118e-08  2.497e-06     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99996835     6.240e-08  7.843e-06     9.313e-10  1.171e-07
0.99989998     3.530e-07  2.496e-05     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99968380     3.818e-07  1.519e-05     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99900001     1.490e-07  3.333e-06     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.99683774     8.941e-08  1.125e-06     7.451e-09  9.376e-08
0.99000001     5.960e-08  4.225e-07     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.96837723     1.490e-08  5.973e-08     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.89999998     2.980e-08  6.837e-08     0.000e+00  0.000e+00
0.68377221     5.960e-08  8.168e-08     5.960e-08  8.168e-08
```

When cos_theta is not close to one, then the accuracy of both methods is very close to each other and to round-off error.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited for major think-o] It looks to me like option 2 will be better, because for a number like `0.000001` for example option 1 will return the sine as 1 while option will return a number just smaller than 1.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in my option since (1-x) preserves the precision not effecting the carried bit. Then for (1+x) the same is true. Then the only thing effecting the carry bit precision is the multiplication. So in both cases there is one single multiplication, so they are both as likely to give the same carry bit error.

Comment: Amazing that your question is about precision and the first 10 answers or so are about speed. Why aren't people answering the question you asked?